# What is the difference between local repository and index?

Tags: git, indexing, commit, repository

What is the difference of the `git add` and `git commit` in simple words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "simple words", `git add` marks files to be added/changed/deleted by your next `git commit`, which finalizes those changes into a commit, adding to your repo's history.

When files are marked to be modified, they're added to the index file/staging-area, which is like taking a picture/snapshot of the state of your working copy.

`git commit` then makes those changes "permanent", though with Git, commits are not as "permanent" as they may be in more traditional source control systems.

That's the simple, high-level answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best analogy you can make is that the index is a staging area.  `git add` (or `git add -p`) updates the content in the index, and `git commit` will create a commit from the content in the index.

Andrew Peterson from NDP Software put a great depiction of how commands affect the various stages of git in their [Visual Git Cheatsheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html).  You can interact with the cheatsheet and see how the various commands moves changes from your workspace, to the index, to the local repo, etc.